# facebook manual login and share and get surrent user details

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api, firefox-os

I'm creating a **firefoxOS**  application using jquery mobile and **cordova**.There is **no api** in cordova for integrating **facebook** and **firefox** applications.

1. I have created a app in facebook and since there is no platform for firefoxOS,I have selected **"website"** as my platform.The problem is that there is **no url** for my firefoxOS application(only index.html),that I can give as redirect url in app settings page of developer.facebook .And also the I have followed steps from this URL (**//developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.3**) and its working fine in the browser as I'm able to login and share and get user details.
   But when i copy/paste the code in my firefox project's **index.html**,the SDK does'nt seem to loading as none of the functionality is working.
2. Apart from the above trial,I have done the "login" flow manually by using this URL `window.open("//www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=APP_ID&response_type=token&redirect_uri=//MY_LOCALHOST/NAME/success.html")`.I'm able to access the current user's **ACCESS_TOKEN** from the success.html which is in server,but unable to access it in my index.html(as it is not hosted anywhere).I have tried to use localStorage,sessionStorage,cookies in success.html . I was wondering if there is any way of getting the **current user's ACCESS_TOKEN** after i have logged in.
   I have used this URL  https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=&redirect_uri=&client_secret=&code= (from //developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens) but it didnt help as I will be getting the access token which is redirected to success.html page which is in server.I need the ACCESS_TOKEN so as to pass as a parameter to this url https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,email,picture&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN in order to get the details of the user currently logged in .

But I'm able to **share** perfectly using this URL `window.open("//www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=APP_ID&link="+encodeURIComponent(urlPost)+"&caption=&description="+encodeURIComponent(message)+"&redirect_uri=MY_LOCALHOST/NAME/success.html")`with respect to the user logged even **without** the access_token (I dont know how its posting to the wall of the current user)

Is there any solution for the above problem? Thank you!!

Comment: The Feed dialog doesn’t need an access token, because it is not your app making an API call to publish; full control lies in the hands of the user. All it needs is for the user to be logged in to Facebook in the browser, they don’t even need to be logged in to your app. As for the login issue, I’d recommend you have a look at how other people have done this, f.e. http://coenraets.org/blog/2014/04/facebook-phonegap-cordova-without-plugin/

Comment: I tried using OpenFB + inappbrowser and the problem is that the firefox is not allowing facebbok login to open .I'm getting the following error ->Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://m.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=...... does not permit framing.